# Problema con un código de JavaScript en la rama del else

Tags: javascript

Me dieron un ejercicio de práctica, en el que tengo que extinguir incendios sólo si hay, y sólo se puede extinguir o bien con un extinguidor o bien con un balde de agua (no vale que en el escenario estén ambos objetos para apagar el fuego).
Si no hay incendio, tengo que avisar de que no hay incendio por apagar.
Y si hay incendio pero no hay extinguidor ni balde de agua, también lo tengo que avisar.

Las variables "hayIncendio" "hayExtintor" y "hayBaldeDeAgua" las carga un usuario con un 0 para indicar NO y con un 1 para indicar SI. pero reitero NO VALE QUE HAYA EXTINTOR Y BALDE DE AGUA A LA VEZ.

El problema que tengo es que cuando pongo que hay incendio, no hay extintor pero si balde de agua, el resultado me aparece como "undefined". No se por qué. Supuestamente, si hay incendio pero no hay extintor, se ejecuta la rama del "else" y vuelve a preguntar si hay fuego y ordena que se apague con agua si hay.

Les dejo el código para ver si pueden ayudarme y desde ya, muchas gracias.

```
let hayIncendio 

let hayExtintor

let hayBaldeDeAgua

let resultado

window.addEventListener("load", iniciarPrograma)

function iniciarPrograma() {
    let sectionMensajeResultado = document.getElementById("mensaje-final")
    sectionMensajeResultado.style.display = "none" 

    let sectionBotonReiniciar = document.getElementById("reinicio")
    sectionBotonReiniciar.style.display = "none"

    let botonCalcular = document.getElementById("boton-calcular")
    botonCalcular.addEventListener("click", calcular)

    let botonReiniciar = document.getElementById("boton-reiniciar")
    botonReiniciar.addEventListener("click", reiniciarPagina)
}

function calcular() {
    obtenerDatos()    
    apagarIncendioSiHayYSiSePuede()
    avisarQueNoHayIncendio()
    mostrarResultado()
}

function obtenerDatos() {
    hayIncendio = document.getElementById("hay-incendio").value
    hayExtintor = document.getElementById("hay-extintor").value
    hayBaldeDeAgua = document.getElementById("hay-balde-de-agua").value
}

function apagarIncendioSiHayYSiSePuede() {
    if(hayIncendio == 1) {
        apagarFuegoConExtintorSiHay()        
    }
    else {
        apagarFuegoSiHayConBaldeDeAguaSiHay()
    } 
}

function apagarFuegoConExtintorSiHay() {
    if(hayExtintor == 1) {
        apagarFuegoConExtintor()
    }
}

function apagarFuegoConExtintor() {
    resultado = "Se ha apagado el fuego con un extintor "
}

function apagarFuegoSiHayConBaldeDeAguaSiHay() {
    if(hayIncendio == 1) {
        apagarFuegoConAguaSiHay()
    }
}

function apagarFuegoConAguaSiHay() {
    if(hayBaldeDeAgua == 1) {
        apagarFuegoConAgua()
    }
}

function apagarFuegoConAgua() {
    resultado = "Se ha apagado el fuego con un balde de agua "
}

function avisarQueNoHayIncendio() {
    if(hayIncendio == 0) {
        resultado = "No hay incendios por apagar ‍"
    }
}

function avisarQueHayIncendioPeroNoHayConQueApagarlo() {
    if((hayIncendio == 1) && (hayExtintor == 0) && (hayBaldeDeAgua == 0)) {
        resultado = "Hay fuego y no hay con qué apagarlo!!! "
    }
}

function mostrarResultado() {
    let spanMensajeFinal = document.getElementById("id-span")
    let sectionMensajeResultado = document.getElementById("mensaje-final")    
    let sectionBotonReiniciar = document.getElementById("reinicio")   

    spanMensajeFinal.innerHTML = resultado
    sectionMensajeResultado.style.display = "block"
    sectionBotonReiniciar.style.display = "block"
}

function reiniciarPagina() {
    location.reload()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que llamas a la función apagarIncendioSiHayYSiSePuede, la cual llama a apagarFuegoConExtintorSiHay

```
function apagarFuegoConExtintorSiHay() {
    if(hayExtintor == 1) {
        apagarFuegoConExtintor()
    }
}
```

Y no hay extintor....entonces que??? ahí termina la ejecución. Te falta un else

```
function apagarFuegoConExtintorSiHay() {
    if(hayExtintor == 1) {
        apagarFuegoConExtintor()
    }
    else{
       apagarFuegoSiHayConBaldeDeAguaSiHay()
    }
}
```

Que es el mismo else que está en apagarIncendioSiHayYSiSePuede

```
function apagarIncendioSiHayYSiSePuede() {
    if(hayIncendio == 1) {
        apagarFuegoConExtintorSiHay()        
    }
    else {
        apagarFuegoSiHayConBaldeDeAguaSiHay()
    } 
}
```

Pero aquí te sobra, estas diciendo que si NO hay incendio lo apagas con agua??

Y aquí paré de revisar tu código, además que es mucho más fácil colocar los if anidados:

```js
let hayIncendio =1;
let hayExtintor =0;
let hayBaldeDeAgua =1;

function apagarIncendioSiHayYSiSePuede() {
    if(hayIncendio == 1) {
        if( hayExtintor == 1)
           return "Se ha apagado el fuego con un extintor ";
        else if( hayBaldeDeAgua == 1)
           return "Se ha apagado el fuego con un balde de agua ";
        else
           return "Hay fuego y no hay con qué apagarlo!!! ";
    }
    else{
      return "No hay incendios por apagar ‍";
    }
}


console.log(apagarIncendioSiHayYSiSePuede());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme!